# i want to share a specific link on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

the website im working on, is a buying and selling website, a user can post in a certain channel (electronics for example), and buyers can view it and express their interest. a user can view posts, and share a certain post through facebook or twitter. now i have done the share with facebook part and its working fine, but to share i have 2 options (or thats what i could find through out the search) it's either i share normally, a link, OR share via my app on facebook, and i want to do the via thingy. when i press share, the share tab opens and everything is fine except that the link to be share is not there, i dont want the user to type it in or copy it, i just want it to be automatically there!

that's the code i used, it takes my app id, and the app domain.

```
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=461240817281750&redirect_uri=https://peaceful-lake-7793.herokuapp.com">share through facebook</a>
```

Comment: Did that advice work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the "link" parameter in your share link - which is why the link isn't showing up for you.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=461240817281750&redirect_uri=https://peaceful-lake-7793.herokuapp.com&link=https://peaceful-lake-7793.herokuapp.com